# Срабатывание :hover на НЕ-дочерних элементах

Tags: css3, html5

Необходимый эффект: при наведении на круг фон всех 4 блоков принимает такой же цвет, как и фон  круга. Как это сделать?

```css
#blocks {
  position: relative;
}
.block {
    display: inline-block;
    outline: 1px dashed #000;
    width: 48%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all linear 1s;
}
.circle {
    background: black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
.circle:hover {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="blocks">
  <div class="block">Blog</div>
  <div class="block">Projects</div>
  <div class="block">Work tools</div>
  <div class="block">CV</div>
</div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: Использовать JS =)

Comment: Без JS нужно!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте flex
Ставьте circle выше, и через order перекидывайте вниз. Далее через соседний селектор

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}
#blocks {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.block {
    display: inline-block;
    outline: 1px dashed #000;
    width: 48%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all linear 1s;
}
.circle {
    order: 2;
    background: black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
.circle:hover {
  background: gray;
}

.circle:hover + #blocks .block {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div id="blocks">
    <div class="block">Blog</div>
    <div class="block">Projects</div>
    <div class="block">Work tools</div>
    <div class="block">CV</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что ж ты опередил меня:(

Comment: бывает всякое... )